# File corruption while being transferred, uploaded, or downloaded

Tags: md5sum

What kinds of things could happen during transfer of a file that would cause the md5sum to change?

To be clear, I am currently concerned with file transfers that *appear* to have completed successfully, but that later turn out to be corrupt as evidenced by a different checksum upon receipt than upon sending.

Answer (score 0):

1. The MD5 algorithm contains some subtle difference (an error) between the sending and receiving side that causes the checksum for some files to be different.
2. The file has been altered in some way in transit.

That's it.